# How do we change the Result Sheet of a Auto edit Time Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script which I use to get DATE & TIME when a cell/column is edited (SheetA!A1) and shows results in (SheetA!B1)

I want to get the Return range value into other (SheetB!A1), Please help me on it.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  if(col === 1 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Stock"  ){
   e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

i Tried using following but could'nt get

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  if(col === 1 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Stock"  ){
   e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Log".getRange(row,1).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(e.range.columnStart == 1 && sh.getName() == "Stock"  ){
    e.source.getSheetByName("SheetB").getRange(e.range.rowStart,1).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```